# Write value to miband with swift

Tags: bluetooth, swift3, characteristics

I have Swift BLE-related question/problem.

I have an MI band which I want to control with my own app.

Reading values from the device is no problem. But now I want to write a value.

I found [this site](http://allmydroids.blogspot.de/2014/12/xiaomi-mi-band-ble-protocol-reverse.html) where most of the characteristics are listed:

```
Start Vibration
Write 8, 2 to Characteristic 0xFF05 (CONTROL_POINT).
```

So I want to start the vibration with the following:

```
if cc.uuid.uuidString == "FF05"{
     let data: Data = "8, 2".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
     miBand.writeValue(data, for: cc, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
}
```

I tried it with other characteristics, too, but none of them worked. No error, no response, nothing.

Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

I could manage to send something to my Raspberry via Bluetooth. So it seems that the current firmware on the Mi band no longer supports the data I send. I also noticed that you can't read all of the characteristics anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Check CBChaaracteristic property was write or other.
If property is write then request data to write CBCharacteristic and get response from peripheral.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is the data you try to write.
Try the following:

```
if cc.uuid.uuidString == "FF05"{
  let bytesToWrite:[UInt8] = [8, 2];
  let data = NSData(bytes: bytesToWrite, length: bytesToWrite.count)
  miBand.writeValue(data, for: cc, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
}
```

For the Mi Band 2 they also changed the protocol, so it might be possible that also for the Mi Band 1 you have to use characteristic `2A06` instead of `FF05`